# Running jsp page hosted in Linux VM from other machine through JSP hosted in windows through APACHE TOMCAT

Tags: java, linux, jsp, tomcat, virtual-machine

Hi i have hosted a jsp page in my Apache Tomcat 7 server in Windows 7.

My computer is connected to network. Initially that page was not accessed from other computer in the network. Later i added the port 8080 to firewall Inbound Rules it worked.

The real problem is,
I have a VM in which Linux is installed and TOmcat is running in it. I have hosted a page in it. say hello.jsp. 
when i access it from my local machine using `http://192.168.202.135:8080/hello.jsp`, (where "192.168.202.135" is my VM's Ip) It is accessible.

I have written a code in the jsp page say win.jsp hosted in my windows 7.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JSP  Page.</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="http://192.168.202.135:8080/hello.jsp">Run jsp in linux</a>

</body>
</html>
```

When i click the link `Run jsp in linux`, it is working. But when i click that link from other machine it is not.
why is it so??
I have hosted it in my machine. WHen a user in other machine click it should access the page right?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
The page hosted in the VM can be accessed only by the host machine.
The code i have written will just make a link to the page in the VM.
But it should hit from the host machine.
How it can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is your VMs IP-address it won't necessarily be reachable by other users. That depends on how you have defined your Host/VM network.

Comment: How can i change that?? It should be accessible by other users.

Comment: That depends on what virtualization technology you're using, and your network. But usually, there's a network setting called "bridged" which works in most cases.

Comment: I have installed linux in VMware Player.

Comment: Check chapter 7 in the [VMWare Player Getting Started Guide](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/desktop/vmware_player50.pdf) and see if you can find someting useful there.